# Лояльность самооценки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, голоса-против, голоса-за

Как относиться (с учетом вашей рейтинговой системы) к бонусам?

Такая ситуация: у чужого ответа 3 голоса, у моего тоже 3.
Ты понимаешь, что твоё решение лучше, но тебе нравится и решение чужое. 
Ставить + или нет в этом случае? Ведь тогда тебя конкурент обгонит.

Я для себя решил всё-таки жмякать (на +). И фиг с ним, что решения чужих людей, пусть даже и менее хорошие - надо поощрять.
Направьте...

Мне очень нравится атмосфера на вашем сайте.
Редко такое встретишь.
Не смог найти ссылку на поддержку, поэтому пишу сюда.

Comment: Я вам уже половину ответа написал, если что )

Comment: Кстати, тут за голосование за чужие ответы в тех вопросах, где есть ваш ответ дают знак ["Спортивное поведение"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship)

Comment: А чтобы обратиться к другому участнику — начните комментарий с @ИмяУчастника.

Comment: @pegoopik – вот так.

Comment: @PashaPash, восстановил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, работает:)

Comment: @pegoopik каждый сам для себя решает как поступать в том или ином случае. Если решение *конкурента* лучше то мне не жалко *плюсануть*, если есть *недостатки* то в этом случае можно ограничиться комментарием к ответу с указанием *недостатка* данного ответа(ответ ведь может быть улучшен), а в целом мне хочется верить что большая часть собравшихся здесь людей отвечают не только из за рейтинга

Comment: @Bald, рейтинг очень хороший мотиватор. Я в любой ситуации всегда рад кому-то помочь "ответом", но рейтинг, скажем так, подогревает желание:)

Comment: ну *мериться* чем либо мне кажется заложено в человеческой основе :)

Comment: Я стараюсь всегда ставить плюс хорошим конкурирующим ответам. С другой стороны, если я вижу, что более хороший ответ имеет меньше плюсов, чем менее хороший, я стараюсь добавить ему плюсов, чтобы он взлетел. «Что припрячешь, то погубишь; что раздашь, вернётся снова.»

Comment: Бывает, что ответил на что-нибудь, а чуть позже появляется другой ответ, и я объективно вижу, что он лучше моего, более полно отвечает на исходный вопрос. Свой ответ стирать неохота, пусть лежит, но новому ответу ставлю плюс, чтобы вопрошающий пошёл по правильному пути.

Comment: "Ведь тогда тебя конкурент обгонит" Лол, у дрессированной капиталистической Мани вся мотивация основана на удовлетворении животных инстинктов доминирования. Хорошо вас обработала рыночная экономика, теперь никто даже не думает о том, что жить можно и по-другому, поэтому из вашего рабства нет выхода.

Comment: Раб социума живет в агонии и страхе быть хуже, чем кто-то, поэтому всегда пытается возвыситься вместо того, чтобы просто быть счастливым. Раб социума пытается сделать из свободных людей рабов социума, уговаривает принять идеологию, что надо не просто стать лучше, а лучше чем кто-то. Раб социума пропагандирует, что нужно добиваться ценностей и страдать, если ты их не добился. Раб социума убеждает, что нужно конкурировать, а не увеличивать всеобщее счастье. Раб социума игнорирует страдающих и помогает только тем, кому и так хорошо.

Comment: Зачем рабам социума деньги, зачем им ценности и успех? Они все равно найдут причину, почему их самооценка недостаточна, найдут причину почувствовать себя хуже других, чтобы снова чего-то добиваться. Рабы социума ищут причину для доминирования вместо того, чтобы испытывать счастье просто так. Надо забирать деньги у рабов социума, свободный человек использует их на свободу, а раб социума потратит на рабство. Рабу хватит кандалов и соломенной подстилки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, где же половина ответа?

Comment: @Qwertiy так пропала, нельзя же было публиковать. А теперь уже всё сказали в комментариях.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ответом удобнее читать ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а ещё принять и голосовать!;-)

Comment: @Qwertiy пока нет времени и сил написать нормальный ответ)

Comment: принимать их такак есть, эти бонусы :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё зависит от ваших приоритетов.

### Помочь остальным посетителям

**Разумное решение:** не ставить плюс. В долгосрочной перспективе это повышает шанс, что у хорошего ответа оценка будет выше. Это упростит поиск лучшего ответа будущими посетителями.

**Дерзкое решение:** поставить конкуренту минус. Ваш ответ окажется чуточку выше и может получить больше внимания.

**Запрещённое решение:** насоздавать фейковых аккаунтов и накидать себе плюсов, чтобы ни у кого не возникало сомнений о качестве. Чревато неприятными последствиями.

### Нафармить побольше репы

**Разумное решение:** не ставить плюс. При незначительном разрыве плюсы часто достаются обоим постам, но первому всё-таки везёт чуточку больше.

**Дерзкое решение:** поставить конкуренту минус. Если снять минус до таймаута, то снятия репы с вас не будет, но часть посетителей увидит ваш ответ первым.

**Запрещённое решение:** насоздавать фейковых аккаунтов...

### Получить значок за спортивное поведение

**Разумное решение:** поставить плюс. Ответы с несколькими заплюсованными ответами на дороге не валяются, ловите шанс.

**Дерзкое решение:** отсутствует, в рамках правил сайта значок не начитерить.

**Запрещённое решение:** поставить плюс, затем, если у вашего ответа оценка 0, с фейка поставить плюс и своему ответу тоже, чтобы ваш плюс засчитался в пользу значка.

### Заработать себе на загробную карму

**Разумное решение:** поставить плюс, если ответ конкурента качественный.

**Дерзкое решение:** отсутствует.

**Запрещённое решение:** отсутствует.

Comment: А у нас точно ботоводство запрещено?.. Может просто не поощряемо? Если второе, то дерзких вариантов больше будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Альтернативные аккаунты разрешены только при условии, что при наличии двух аккаунтов пользователь не делает ничего, что не мог бы сделать с одним. Соответственно, голосование за свой пост, голосование за один пост двумя аккаунтами и прочие подобные действия запрещены.

Comment: Ну, положим  беру два акка и вопрос на коий можно дать два и более ответов. Отвечаю с каждого акка хорошим ответом и плюсую вопрос другого акка. Я бы и одним акком плюсанул бы ответ другого акка. Значит я ничего не нарушил и коплю "спортивное поведение" =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Представьте, что оба поста принадлежат одному аккаунту. Как вы сможете заплюсовать один из постов из под аккаунта, под которыми они написаны? Условие не выполнено.

Answer (score 1):

Я себя постоянно на подобном ловлю. Особенно, если на вопрос отвечает участник с репутацией больше моей - никак не могу избавиться от мыслей вроде "если я его плюсану, то никогда по репутации его не догоню".

Но вопроса про минус у меня не возникает - я либо плюсану чужой ответ, либо ничего делать не буду. Если посмотреть мои голоса, то плюсов у меня ~90% от всех голосов. Обычно минусую только явно плохие вопросы/ответы.

В общем, я бы советовал либо плюсовать (если ответ хорош), либо пройти мимо. Но не надо его минусовать, мы же тут в одной лодке и у нас общие цели.